# Multiple imports in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How do people get around this issue:

A controller (say controller.py) imports two models (say a_model.py and b_model.py):

```
from app.model import a_model
from app.model import b_model
```

Now let's say that a_model wants to use a function in b_model (let's say it wants to get something from b_model where an `id` of the record is from a query in a_model, so I do (in a_model):

```
from app.model import b_model
```

Now since our controller has already imported b_model.py and a_model.py is attempting to do the same, we break the application.

Can someone tell me the best way around this? Maybe use a proxy? Or a library loader?

Comment: Wouldn't they just be accessed as `a_model.id` and `b_model.id`?

Comment: I haven't tried that, sorry for my n00bness but can you give me an example?

Comment: What do you mean by "break the application"? Is some kind of error thrown? It should be safe to import the same module multiple times from different places.

Comment: See the answer from Андрей, that's the issue I'm having.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no problem with importing a module from two different modules in Python. Maybe your particular design makes it a problem, but it's not something Python imposes.

Anyhow, you could probably solve the problem by moving common stuff from `a_model` and `b_model` to some other module, i.e. `model_common`, and importing that from both `a_model` and `b_model`.

Comment: Interesting idea. I should have stated that I'm using Google App Engine, so the models contact the 'table' so to speak, hence why I keep the logic in the same model as the 'table'.

Answer (score 4):

It is fine as long as you don't have cicrcular references, ie.

```
main --> model.a_model -> model.b_model
     \-> model.b_model
```

Is ok.

But if you add `import a_model` from `b_model.py` things would get complicated as there would be no way to order loading in such way that for each module all prerequisites would be satisfied.

Python handles this situation less nicely as one would expect and instead of reporting about circular imports, raises exception about undefined symbol in one of the modules.

Comment: So is there a way to get around this? Eli mentioned a common model, but is there not a more elegant solution?

Comment: It depends on the context. Why exactly do you need to reference A from B and B from A?

Comment: You can't do circular references in a model class in any case, no matter how you organize them. Are you trying to do mutual `ReferenceProperty`ies?

Comment: That's right. Provided with context we can advise logic-specific way to avoid circular references.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
class A(db.Model):
  b = db.ReferenceProperty(B)

class B(db.Model):
  a = db.ReferenceProperty(A)
```

If so, the easy fix is probably to turn one of them into a weak reference:

```
class A(db.Model):
  b = db.ReferenceProperty()

class B(db.Model):
  a = db.ReferenceProperty(A)
```

This is a crappy solution, no question. I'm not sure if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: Nitpick: It's not a 'weak reference', which has other connotations.